# É possível instanciar uma conexão com o banco de dados manualmente usando o Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu gostaria de gerenciar minhas conexões manualmente, para que os usuários pudessem informar o endereço do servidor, porém o Entity cria a string de conexão diretamente no arquivo de config, o único modo seria alterar aquele arquivo todas as vezes.

Porém eu queria fazer isso através de código, como se estivesse instanciando uma conexão manualmente ou apenas informando a string de conexão via código sem modificar o arquivo de configurações. É possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Uma forma de se fazer isso é passando como parâmetro do construtor do contexto. [Uma das sobrecargas do construtor aceita uma `string`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.)

Com esta abordagem é possível trabalhar de duas maneiras: 1) mantendo todas as conexões no arquivo `web.config` e construir o contexto passando o **nome da conexão** como parâmetro; e 2) passar como parâmetro do construtor **a *string* de conexão completa**.

```
public class SeuContexto : DbContext
{
    public SeuContexto(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

E o uso poderia ser algo como

```
var context = new SeuContexto("uma string de conexao gigante aqui");
```